# Drupal - bring node form from Create Content > [Node Type] to a custom menu

Tags: drupal-6

at this time, I'm able to add software node type by using node type form in Create Content > Software menu. But I want to place this form to a custom menu. This is my menu:

```
'software/add' => array(
            'title' => 'Add Software',
            'page callback' => '???',
            'access callback' => TRUE,
        ),
```

I'm managed to make an admin form in custom menu by using page callback and system_settings_form. So I guess I must work around with page callback, but I don't know how to do it with node type form.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, sometimes I need this kind of menu items, the code follows:

```
$items['software/add'] = array(
  'title' => 'Add Software',
  'page callback' => 'node_add',
  'page arguments' => array('software'),
  'access callback' => 'node_access',
  'access arguments' => array('create', 'software'),
  'file' => 'node.pages.inc',
  'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'node'),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply go to the menu item and re-assign it to your other menu in the GUI. Or you could look to the [node.module](http://drupalcode.org/viewvc/drupal/drupal/modules/node/node.module?revision=1.947.2.29&view=markup&pathrev=DRUPAL-6-20), which is the module that currently handles that hook_menu implementation:

```
$items['node/add'] = array(
  'title' => 'Create content',
  'page callback' => 'node_add_page',
  'access callback' => '_node_add_access',
  'weight' => 1,
  'file' => 'node.pages.inc',
);
```